# Best method to parallelize PySpark elaboration on Dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, parallel-processing

I'm new to Spark and I'm trying to learn how to parallelize the execution of the following code:

```
# init of results dataframe, empty
schema = StructType([
    StructField('user', StringType()),
    StructField('mean', FloatType()),
    StructField('std_dev', FloatType())
])
df_result = spark.createDataFrame([], schema)

# for each distinct user:
# - build table of his transactions
# - recon mean and std of 'importo'
# - append new row to df_result about this user
for usr in users:
    # get usr transactions by union of the rows regarding this user
    bons = df_bon[df_bon['user']==usr]
    rics = df_ric[df_ric['user']==usr]
    tot = bons.union(rics)
    # LEFT ANTI JOIN to delete all the fraudolent transactions
    no_frauds = tot.join(df_frodi, ['transaction_id'], "leftanti")
    # recon mean and standard deviation, it is a 1-row dataframe
    no_frauds = no_frauds.select(_mean(col('importo')).alias('mean'), _stddev(col('importo')).alias('std')).collect()
    # create dataframe with user field, then append it to the result dataframe via union
    df_result = df_result.union(spark.createDataFrame([(usr, no_frauds[0][0], no_frauds[0][1])], ['user', 'mean', 'std']))
```

I would like to understand how to enhance this code, every suggestion is welcome, forgive me if I wrote bad code but this is the first time ever I approach Spark :)

I know that the problem is the for loop, which doesn't implement any parallel logic, but I would like to know what are the best practises in order to parallelize it (e.g. is it ok to use the standard `ThreadPool` method?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My anwser will be partial because you do not provide any data to fully understand your case.

But something like :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df_result = (
    df_bon.union(df_rics)
    .where(F.col("user").isin(users))
    .join(df_frodi, ["transaction_id"], "leftanti")
    .groupBy("user")
    .agg(F.avg("importo").alias("mean"), F.stddev("importo").alias("std"))
)
```